# Bootstrap containers not static

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns inside a container. And I have multiple containers one below the other.

I want the left columns to move downwards as the content inside them increases, without effecting the right columns.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="content_left" style="border: solid 1px gainsboro;padding-bottom: 6px;">
      <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px;"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>  </span>
      <div class="left-title">Speciality</div>
      <div class="content-left1">
        <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></span>
        <div class="left-title">Multi Speciality</div>
        <div class="left_options">
          <input value="1" id="ca1" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca1"><span></span>Heart</label>
          <br>

          <input value="2" id="ca2" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca2"><span></span>General</label>
          <br>

          <input value="3" id="ca3" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca3"><span></span>Dental</label>
          <br>

          <input value="16" id="ca16" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca16"><span></span>Maternity</label>
          <br>

          <input value="17" id="ca17" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca17"><span></span>Orthopedic</label>
          <br>

          <input value="18" id="ca18" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca18"><span></span>Pediatric</label>
          <br>

          <input value="19" id="ca19" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca19"><span></span>Mental Health</label>

          <br>
        </div>
        <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px;"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> </span>
        <div class="left-title">Speciality</div>
        <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px;"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> </span>
        <div class="left-title">Speciality</div>
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">


  <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3" style="border: solid 1px gainsboro; margin-top: -120px; padding-bottom: 20px; ">


    <div class="content_header col-md-12" style="border-bottom: solid 1px gainsboro;">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <img src="#" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 Hospital_name" style="border: none;font-size: 20px; color: gainsboro;">
        Cloud Nine Hospital
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 Hospital_speciality" style="  color: darkblue; margin-top: 12px;">
        Maternity Hospital
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 hospital_location" style="color: gainsboro;margin-top: 12px;">
        Bangalore
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">
        ★★★★★
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        4.2

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Hospital_Details">
      <div class="col-xs-5" style="margin-left: -3.55%;">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-7" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 20px;">
        Consultation fee: <span style="margin-left: 10%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span>  <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span>
        <br>
        <br>Ward Charges <span style="margin-left: 13.5%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span>  <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>Contact: <span style="margin-left: 23%; color: darkblue">Jayanagar</span>  <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: skyblue">9785461238</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-xs-5">View More Details <span> > </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
            <input type="submit" value="Book Appointment" style="background-color: orangered; border: none; color: white; border-radius: 5px;" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

How can I make the left container independent of the right one. ? 
[image]

Comment: Qhaym, Please share your div structure or source. With out that can't give a solution

Comment: @Qhayum, Without providing code snippet, Cannot solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Changed your code. Here is the code.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="content_left" style="border: solid 1px gainsboro;padding-bottom: 6px;">
      <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px;"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>  </span>
      <div class="left-title">Speciality</div>
      <div class="content-left1">
        <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></span>
        <div class="left-title">Multi Speciality</div>
        <div class="left_options">
          <input value="1" id="ca1" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca1"><span></span>Heart</label>
          <br>

          <input value="2" id="ca2" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca2"><span></span>General</label>
          <br>

          <input value="3" id="ca3" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca3"><span></span>Dental</label>
          <br>

          <input value="16" id="ca16" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca16"><span></span>Maternity</label>
          <br>

          <input value="17" id="ca17" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca17"><span></span>Orthopedic</label>
          <br>

          <input value="18" id="ca18" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca18"><span></span>Pediatric</label>
          <br>

          <input value="19" id="ca19" class="handleclick" type="checkbox" name="ca">
          <label for="ca19"><span></span>Mental Health</label>

          <br>
        </div>
        <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px;"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> </span>
        <div class="left-title">Speciality</div>
        <span class="expand-collapse-text" style="cursor: pointer; margin-left: 7px;"> <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> </span>
        <div class="left-title">Speciality</div>
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9" style="border: solid 1px gainsboro; margin-top: -120px; padding-bottom: 20px; ">


    <div class="content_header col-md-12" style="border-bottom: solid 1px gainsboro;">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <img src="#" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 Hospital_name" style="border: none;font-size: 20px; color: gainsboro;">
        Cloud Nine Hospital
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 Hospital_speciality" style="  color: darkblue; margin-top: 12px;">
        Maternity Hospital
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 hospital_location" style="color: gainsboro;margin-top: 12px;">
        Bangalore
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">
        ★★★★★
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        4.2

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Hospital_Details">
      <div class="col-xs-5" style="margin-left: -3.55%;">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-7" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 20px;">
        Consultation fee: <span style="margin-left: 10%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span>  <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span>
        <br>
        <br>Ward Charges <span style="margin-left: 13.5%; color: skyblue">Rs: 500</span>  <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: gainsboro">Onwards</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>Contact: <span style="margin-left: 23%; color: darkblue">Jayanagar</span>  <span style="margin-left: 3%; color: skyblue">9785461238</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
          <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="#" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-xs-5">View More Details <span> > </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-5">
            <input type="submit" value="Book Appointment" style="background-color: orangered; border: none; color: white; border-radius: 5px;" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This will work. @Anil Please checkout the [Bootstrap Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) . Your code was disorganized.

Comment: Hi @Manoj This worked to an extent. But the thing is I want the left  columns to expand vertically as content increases and only the left columns to move downwards. The right columns should stay where they are. Because I have multiple rows... Sorry if wasn't clear.. but Is this possible ???

Comment: Sorry but you are using too much of inline style. You need to restructure your code following the guidelines of the documentation. Inline styles should be avoided.